# Conditional type for an array to provide eirther an Error or a generic when destructured

Tags: typescript, destructuring, conditional-types, generic-type-parameters

In my Typescript project I have a Result type that I return from functions, containing either an error or some data. It can be either of the form `[Error, null]`, or `[null, Data]`. For example:

```
type Result<Data> = [ Error | null, Data | null ]

function randomSuccess(): Result<string> {
    if ( Math.random() > 0.5 ) {
        return [ null, 'success' ]
    else {
        return [ new Error( 'oh no' ), null ]
    }
}

const [ err, result ] = randomSuccess()
if ( err ) {
    .... // can now handle the extracted error and result
```

I would like Typescript to check that only one of the Error or Data is ever not null. For example:

```
    ...
        return [ new Error( 'oh no' ), 'success' ]
```

should throw an error.

My initial attempt at writing a type for this was with conditional types:

```
type Result<Data> = null extends Error ? [ null, Data ] : [ Error, null ]
```

This compiles fine when the function returns an error. However when returning valid data - for example `return [ null, 'success' ]` - the compiler complains:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Error'

I think I understand the compiler error: in my type definition `Error` is not a parameter so `null extends Error` will always be false. However I don't know where to go from here.

How can I make a type that is either `[Error, null]`, or `[null, Data]`, and never `[Error, Data]`?

Comment: If anyone has a good dupetarget for this question, please @ ping me when you vote to close so I can remove the answer below. I didn't find one, but it seems likely to me that it's there. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where the parts of the union are the two tuples (arrays) that represent the two possible states:

```typescript
type Result<Data> =
    [ null, Data ]      // Success
    |
    [ Error, null ];    // Failure
```

A `Result<Data>` can *either* have one form or the other, but can't have `null` in both places, and can't have `Error, Data`. (Also can't have a length other than 2.)

Here's an example:

```typescript
type Result<Data> =
    [ null, Data ]      // Success
    |
    [ Error, null ];    // Failure
    
function random(): Result<Date> {
//                        ^^^^−−−− Using `Date` for the `Data` type  argument
//                                just for example
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        // Fail
        return [new Error(), null];
    }
    // Succeed
    return [null, new Date()];
}

const a = random();
if (a[0]) {
    // TypeScript now knows that `a[0]` is an `Error`
    console.log(`Error: ${a[0].message}`);
} else {
    // TypeScript now knows that `a[1]` is a `Date`
    console.log(`Success at ${a[1].toString()}`);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAEQIbCwPigF4AoKMqAbSgDsVkAaKbXKAXXPIHpOoBlRAMYCE8UuQA+YslQCiAJzkB7OY1rJkbANwduUAGJYAlskRyIUqMQBmiagOCHF1KHKzUAJooC2ACgCUAFywCCjozBAEAN7Euhxx8QlQAHopSYBIRBlpUACq8IbUAOZQAAbhxVBWylDAABbQpThY5aCQUFhyBYheENTAUABWiPB9lXJQEAAeWF5gyOYchlZQPgCyODUAdK4e3v5QaFAADBsArH5Q0Ym6BsYWHGbAps4U1BAA7lDySnL+qnSsmgsAF8LLp+EIIBB3BYHk9KGoGDR3kwcBB-ADiCDiAInMM2kQXG5PL4-IDFsssBRDqxzpcuDwACrgCC8ARyQxgPrURQfADW3Le8GqNRwJUp1PKhiFbhKX2UxQsOOo8EUcw2yEUBR8xTlciCABJIuLWBtuvB4FgChAgcVSZjxsh4NA6WRdEzIKz2ZyaDyoPyeULaqLipSAIysSXSkplRW41UQdWa7Xg4Tmtp9Q1hk3ARS8YDswr+G12oFAA)

Comment: Thanks, very informative! Probably a separate question, but is it possible for Typescript to perform correct type checking when destructuring the array, rather than needing `a[0]` and `a[1]`?

Comment: @jla - You can use destructuring, but the only problem is that the type guard will only apply to the thing you check. So in the above, for instance, if I replaced `const a= random();` with `const [error, date] = random();` and replaced `a[0]` with `error` and `a[1]` with `date`, it would all work *except* that TypeScript wouldn't know that `data` was definitely not `null` in the `else` branch. If you did `if (data)` it would know (but wouldn't know that `error` wasn't `null` in an `else` branch on that). Whereas ...

Comment: ... as you can see, when doing `if (a[0])`, it narrows the type of `a`, so `a[1]` is known to be not-`null` in the `else` branch. I don't think there's a way around that. But you can usually structure your code so the thing you want is the thing that's narrowed.

Comment: (Sorry, `date`, not `data` in the above.)